# Ruby and Rails: Metaprogramming variables to become class methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, metaprogramming, instance-variables

I'm creating a model called Configuration and I have the following code and I want to make it more dynamic by using metaprogramming.

In a table on the database for Configuration model I have the following data.

```
---------------------------------------------------------
variable_name as string     |  value in text
                            |
company_name                |  MyCompany
welcome_text                |  Welcome to MyCompany's App!
email_order_text            |  You've just created an account with MyCompany.
year_since                  |  2012
----------------------------------------------------------

class Configuration  < ActiveRecord::Base

    #nothing here yet

end

----------------------------------------------------------
```

Currently, the only way to access the company_name is to do the following in rails console:

```
configuration_company_name = Configuration.find_by_variable_name("company_name")
configuration_company_name.company_name

> "MyCompany"
```

I think this is an unacceptable way to do things. First, it will access the database everytime someone checks for the company's name. I think if I could load it when the app starts and doesn't have to access it again because it's in the memory, then it would be better. How can I do something more dynamic so I could access the value "MyCompany" like this.

```
Configuration.company_name

> "MyCompany"
```

The reason to do this is to give allow fast customization of the application.

Comment: Are you sure this is really a problem?  Rails is pretty good about caching requests to the database, so I wouldn't expect a database query every time someone wants the company_name.  As with the famous Donald Knuth quote: "...premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: I think that's part of the problem. When I check the production.log it keeps sending the request to MySQL which is not ideal.

The main issue is to access the variables as class method instead of having to get find_by_variable or where("variable =?", variable) which is ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Configuration  < ActiveRecord::Base
  # loads all the configuration variables to an in-memory
  # static hash during the first access. 
  def self.[](n)
    @config ||= {}.tap { |h| Configuration.all.each{ h[variable_name] = c.value}}
    @config[n]
  end
end
```

Now you can access your configuration as :

```
Configuration["company_name"]
```

If you a large number of configuration parameters, it might be beneficial to pre-load the cache by accessing a configuration parameter in an initializer file. If you have 1000s of configuration variables you might have to consider migrating the cache to `memcached` etc.

If you want to access the configuration parameter as a class method:

```
class Configuration  < ActiveRecord::Base

 klass = class << self; self; end
 Configuration.all.each{|c| klass.send(:define_method, c.variable_name){c.value}}

end
```

Now you can access the parameter as follows:

```
Configuration.company_name
```

Comment: THANKS a lot! Both ways worked perfectly. I tried using define_singleton_method and the define_method, but it only worked inside the console and not on the rails app.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you are getting wrong here,it will be never be  `Configuration.company_name` , thats like access a **Class** property instead of a **Object/Instance** property,

It should be a instance of the Configuration Class. It would still be somewhat acceptable to  use @KandagaBoggu's method in the other answer, but database access still almost everytime or from the Active Record’s query cache.But AR's query cache lives for the duration of a particular action (i.e. request ). You may want use something like Memcached for the objects to survive longer.

Comment: @chim's use case is a valid candidate for singleton pattern. Take a look at the `Rails` module https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails.rb. Or the configuration classes in Sunspot library: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot/lib/light_config.rb.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the db is accessed but because the scope and the number of config variables are changing at this stage, I think that's an OK trade-off for now.

I will probably generate a config file in the initialization based on the model once my variables are more "stable".

Comment: @KandadaBoggu yes, I thought so as well, but I wasn't entirely sure he was going for "Singelton" in this case, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

We can move these constant values into a `yml` file, when the server starts load them into a variable and access it whenever needed.

Comment: That would be a good idea, but the scope of the product is changing so I need to create the config variables on the fly and access them on the runtime. Thanks!